# Is it possible to multi-thread serialize/deserialize while preseving object reference in protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have a big root class that contains all the data.
I can serialize that to one big file with all the references in it preserved.

But is it possible to do this multi-threaded?
Is it already doing it internally?

The only way I know to multi-thread serialize/deserialize is to separate all the data to a different file, but the reference breaks between the file.

Comment: What do you hope to gain by multi-threading? You can't parallelize I/O of a single streamed object, and I doubt your serialization is CPU bound.

Comment: While it is true that reading spead cannot be improved.
Reading and parsing (total process of deserelization) is two different things. While you can't improve reading speed you can improve parsing thing. For example csv parsing cpu vs gpu (28.764s vs 0.77s) : https://github.com/antonmks/nvParse